# Prototype.js: How to OVERWRITE a div, not updating it's content via ajax?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

When I do

`new Ajax.Updater('foo', 'getALifeGuys.php', ...`

this will update the content of

`<div id="foo">`.

But how do i OVERWRITE this div with the result of the ajax call ? The main idea  behind this is that we don't know the parent of the foo-div and the result of the ajax call also contains the `<div id="foo">`.

Comment: so you have <div id="foo"> in your html and then myGangstaBitches.php returns another <div id="foo"> that you want to replace the original with? im sorry im just a touch confused but had to try and answer this with a php file called myGangstaBitches.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe Yes, exactly! Seems to be a common problem btw, have seen others asking this in boards, but no useful answers.

Comment: You can use `parentNode` to get `div#foo`'s parent, and then load into it.

Comment: i see. i don't think that there is an out of the box way of accomplishing a direct overwrite of an element by just replacing it but since they are identical, in  your ajax call back just .remove() the original one from the dom and immediately append the new one. what im a little confused about is why you wouldn't just want to take the data that's in the <div id="foo"> from ur server and place that data into the version of <div id="foo"> already living on your page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`insertion` option](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/), which takes a function as well:

```
new Ajax.Updater('foo', 'getALifeGuys.php', {
    insertion: function(el, response) {
        $(el).replace(response);
    }
});
```

If your `div#foo` is the only child of its parent element, you can as well just pass that parent:

```
new Ajax.Updater($('foo').parentNode, 'getALifeGuys.php', …);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing for you to do, in this instance, is, rather than using `Ajax.Updater`, use `Ajax.Request` which `Ajax.Updater` wraps. Inside the success method of that, you can then use `Element.replace`, to replace the div with id `foo` with the content coming back from your method.